# Using variables inside function from dot sourced .ps1

Tags: function, variables, powershell

I'm trying to create a config.ps1 file which contains all of the variables my scripts needs. Inside those scripts there are several functions. But when i dot source these variables they do not work inside my function. How do i get them to work?

```
. ./config.ps1

function RollOut {
write-host "$Rolling"
}
```

Where $Rolling is defiend in config.ps1 
    $Rolling="Go"

Thanks!

Comment: You're not actually calling the function `RollOut` in your sample code. It worked just fine for me when I added a line `RollOut` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your variables in `config.ps1` available on the global scope.

Change the definition to:

```
$Global:Rolling = "Go"
```

Comment: So nothing needs to be done in the config file? I just have to call them using $Global infront?

Comment: You need to define them as `$Global:xxx` in the config file, then you can call them normally.

Comment: Though having said that, not using `$global` is also working for me in simple examples. Give it a go anyway, might solve your problem and it's probably the right approach for what you're doing.